# How to select sub-classed Custom Elements with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, web-component, subclassing, custom-element

Consider the following:

```
class MyElem extends HTMLElement {};
customElements.define('my-element', MyElem);

class MyMoreSpecificElem extends MyElem {};
customElements.define('my-more-specific-element', MyMoreSpecificElem);
```

In the parlance of object inheritance, instances of the second class have an 'is-a' relationship with the first: a `MyMoreSpecificElem` *is a* `MyElem`.

This relationship is captured in JavaScript:

```
let subclassInstance = document.querySelector('my-more-specific-element');
let parentClass = document.querySelector('my-element').constructor;

subclassInstance instanceof parentClass; // true
```

But I can't think of any way to select all `MyElem`s (including the subclass MyMoreSpecificElem) using CSS selectors. A tag selector would only get the superclass or subclass, and all of the relationship description selectors I'm aware of (e.g. ~, >) are about position in the document, not class hierarchy.

I mean, sure, I can add a CSS class in the constructor and select by that, the call to `super` would ensure that even subclass instances could be selected that way. But that's gnarly. Is there a way to do this in pure CSS?

Comment: There's no parent selectors (yet) in CSS. Is there any existing "pair" of elements which you could select with a single CSS selector?

Comment: @Teemu I don't want a parent selector (well, I mean I *do*, but that's not the question here). I want a selector that will give me all elements that are related by class hierarchy (in JS `instanceof` terms), not document position terms. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: (Off-topic) Could you share where you came across this use case/problem? A book, a video, a course?

Comment: I mean is there currently a tag selector in CSS with which you can select two different tags? I can't imagine any.

Comment: @Alex if I make, for example, a `shiny-button` element, and a subclass element `shiny-round-floating-super-awesome-button`, I still want all of the styles for `shiny-button` to apply (unless I override them with a higher-specificity selector).

Comment: @Teemu me either, but if I want, say, all the buttons in the document, and I subclass `HTMLButtonElement`, shouldn't I get those too? Or at least have that option somehow? I mean, if I know ahead of time I can do `button, my-button` but that won't work with arbitrary subclasses.

Comment: With the code you have, there is no way to do this with pure CSS. There are plenty of alternatives, but it's not clear what you'll accept.

Comment: @skyline3000 do you have anything better than my idea of adding a CSS class in the constructor to select on? I'd accept that.

Comment: If you don't want to add a class (or perhaps a data-attribute) the most straightforward thing to do is use getElementsByTagName() twice and combine the resulting html collections.

Comment: @skyline3000 if I were going to do that I'd do `document.querySelectorAll('my-element, my-more-specific-element')`. Problem is still the same: that only works if you know the specific tag names ahead of time, your code cannot work with someone else's extension (i.e. arbitrary subclasses of your custom element). As for the data attribute, that's more or less the same as adding a CSS class. Ah well. Maybe someday.

Comment: @Teemu ok, maybe the built in is a bad example since we're supposed to extend those with the `is` attribute rather than classes. But the broader point still applies.

Comment: The root of the issue lies in `querySelectorAll` method, and in the way how it creates the node list. This ofcourse is implementation-dependent, but if we assume the implemetations are based even roughly on the same principals, they just traverse the DOM tree, and search for matches to selectors ([see Webkit implementation](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/WebCore/dom/SelectorNodeList.cpp?rev=41093#L61)). Maybe you need to fork `querySelectorAll` to achieve what you need ..?

Answer (score 2):

Why not have the base component class add either a `className` value or an attribute that will be set for both the base component class and all of the sub-component classes. Then your CSS can be set based on this `className` value or attribute.

```js
class MyBaseEl extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.classList.add('my-base-el');
    this.innerHTML = '<div>Base El</div>';
  }
}

customElements.define('my-base-el', MyBaseEl);

class MySubEl extends MyBaseEl {
  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    this.innerHTML = '<div>Sub El</div>';
  }
}

customElements.define('my-sub-el', MySubEl);
```

```css
.my-base-el {
  background-color: #FF0;
  display: block;
  outline: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcomponentsjs/1.0.22/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<my-base-el></my-base-el>
<my-sub-el></my-sub-el>
```

This uses a `className` value to allow the CSS to get at all of the elements that are `MyBaseEl` or a subclass.

Or like this:

```js
class MyBaseEl extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.setAttribute('my-base-el', '');
    this.innerHTML = '<div>Base El</div>';
  }
}

customElements.define('my-base-el', MyBaseEl);

class MySubEl extends MyBaseEl {
  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    this.innerHTML = '<div>Sub El</div>';
  }
}

customElements.define('my-sub-el', MySubEl);
```

```css
[my-base-el] {
  background-color: #FF0;
  display: block;
  outline: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcomponentsjs/1.0.22/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<my-base-el></my-base-el>
<my-sub-el></my-sub-el>
```

This uses an attribute to allow the CSS to get at all of the elements that are `MyBaseEl` or a subclass.

**UPDATE**

The only other way of setting CSS for multiple element tags is to know what all of them are and make the css work for all of them like this:

```css
my-base-el, my-sub-el, my-other-sub-el, the-third-sub-el {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

But, if someone else can create additional sub-classes then you would need to add to the list.

**UPDATE 2**

Why not just set the `:host` in the base class and have it use a CSS variable for the styles you want the user to be able to change. Then everything will inherit that `:host` css and display like you want.

Comment: Yeah, that's more-or-less what I suggested in the question. I'd really prefer to avoid it if at all possible.

Comment: Yeah I suggested that in a comment to Teemu on the question, but it doesn't allow for seamless extensibility. The whole point of web components is re-use. At any rate, I appreciate the attempt. +1.